# UCanAccessSQLException: constraint violation

Tags: java, composite-primary-key, ucanaccess

I'm having problems with my Java program.
I'm using MS Access as a database and UCanAccess to connect to the database.

When I'm trying to insert a text into the database, I get an Exception:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; ENTRIES_PRIMARYKEY table: ENTRIES
```

This is the SQL statement, that results in the exception:

```
"INSERT INTO Entries (Text, Title, Date, Time) VALUES"
                + "(\"" + text + "\", \"" + title + "\", \"" + date  + "\", \"" + time + "\");";
```

The primary keys of table Entries is (Title, Date).
The information I'm inserting does not exist in the table.

I've made a System.out.println() containing the same string to make sure the variables contain the correct information, and they do.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue as stated. Run `console.bat` or `console.sh` (as appropriate) from the folder containing the UCanAccess JAR file. When prompted, enter the full path to the Access database. Check the "Loaded Indexes:" section of the output and verify that you see `Primary Key  on ENTRIES Columns: (TITLE,DATE)`.

Comment: It just says "Given file does not exist". I don't understand, I've even copy/pasted the directory and made sure that the filename is correct. I'm even looking at the file - it's right there!

Comment: Are you including the .accdb or .mdb file extension, as appropriate? If you are working on a non-Windows machine are you sure that the full path, filename, and extension match exactly (case-sensitive)?

Comment: I'm working on a Windows machine, and I'm using the correct path/filename/extension.. But I'm not sure about the including. How so?
Let me specify my problem: I tried inserting a row, and it worked. But when I tried to insert more rows, the problem occurred. I'm not sure why it worked before or why it doesn't work anymore. Where am I supposed to include the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(from comment to question:)*

> I tried inserting a row, and it worked. But when I tried to insert more rows, the problem occurred.

If the Primary Key for the table is `(Title, Date)` then the values in those two columns (fields) must be unique across all rows. That is, you can insert a row that looks like

```
Text        Title   Date        Time
----------  ------  ----------  --------
some text   Title1  2015-06-01  05:56:15
```

but if you try to insert another row like this

```
Text        Title   Date        Time
----------  ------  ----------  --------
other text  Title1  2015-06-01  06:15:44
```

the insert will fail because that combination of `Title` and `Date` already exists in the table. Yes, that row "doesn't exist" because the `Text` and `Time` values are different, but the Primary Key constraint doesn't care; it only looks at the `Title` and `Date` columns.

If you really need to insert that second row then you'll need to change the Primary Key for the table.

Comment: I was using a different title, so there should be no constraint violation.. that's my problem, and I'm still stuck :/

Comment: @Jákup Then you'll need to provide us with a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clearly demonstrate the issue. No offense, but I'm convinced that your code is simply not doing what you *think* it is doing.

Comment: I think I have figured out the problem. I do not, however, know the solution.
Adding a new entry today, I see that it works. But adding one again adds to the same error. This looks like that the primary key is in fact ONLY the date.
I've taken a screenshot of the design view of my database here:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/xekjte.jpg

In my previous examples, I've translated the attribute names, but it's the same order (text, title, date, time). In the picture, you can see that there are 2 keys and when I mouse over them, it says "The field is part of the table's Primary Key".